# Spinner - Add something in a spinner by click

Tags: java, android, spinner

What i want to do is to add something in a spinner by clicking on it and then click in a "add option" tha appears in the spinner. I am new to android development. Can somebody help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an adapter (for example, an [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)) and then bind it to your spinner using the `Spinner.setAdapter()` method.

After you override the `Adapter.onItemSelected()` method in your `onItemSelectedListener`, you can use a function like this (if you've implemented your `onItemSelectedListener` within the same class that you've declared your adapter called `arrayAdapter`):

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
    View view, int pos, long id) {

    if (parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals("Add Item")) {
         arrayAdapter.add(new object());  //object is what your array contains
    }
}
```

Look at the spinner [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html) for the in-between steps.

Comment: and can i populate a spinner with a array adapter and from a sqlite database on the same time?

Comment: When using an sqlite database, it would probably be easier to use a cursoradapter instead.  With some translation functions, you could use an array adapter too though.

Answer (score 0):

For an example of dynamically adding items to a Spinner, take a look at [Populate Spinner dynamically in android from edit text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999262)

Other than this, what have you got so far?  Where specifically are you stuck?

Comment: i can populate a spinner from an existing sqlite database. But i want to add a functionality that allows me to click on an existing option that exist inside the spinner for instance "Add a new something" and when i click in this option i am redirect to a new activity in wich i can add a new "something" to the spinner.